# How to display a saved value initially in select2 field

Tags: javascript, json, jquery-select2

I'm using select2 3.5.3 to grab remote data from a JSON file in order to populate a field in a Drupal node edit form.

My javascript works great to get values when there is no stored value, some placeholder text is displayed to give instructions to the user, however when I load up a page that already has a stored value, nothing is shown in the select2.

You'll see that the input has a value, however what I'd like is for the text to be displayed, which can be matched from the JSON file.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="myfieldid" name="myfieldname" value="my value"  style="display: none;">
```

JS:

```
$("#edit-field-crm-link-und-0-value").select2({
minimumInputLength: 3,
placeholder: "Start typing to search for course titles",
ajax: {
    url: "http://offthehookdesign-domain.uk/available-courses.txt",
    dataType: 'json',
    type: "GET",
    quietMillis: 50,
    data: function (term) {
        return {
            term: term
        };
    },
results: function(data, page ) {
return { results: data}
}
}
});
```

Seems like this should be possible using initSelection, but the closest I can get is to get the value of the input using the following JS:

```
initSelection: function(element, callback) {
var id=$(element).val();
    if (id!=="") {
        callback({id:id, text : $(element).attr('value')});
    }
}
```

Obviously I would like to display the the text that matches this ID value in the original JSON file.